# Resnet-50 adversarial training with cleverhans FGSM accuracy stuck at 5%

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cleverhans

I am facing a strange problem when adversarially training a resnet-50, and I am not sure whether is's a logical error, or a bug somewhere in the code/libraries.
I am adversarially training a resnet-50 thats loaded from Keras, using the FastGradientMethod from cleverhans, and expecting the adversarial accuracy to rise at least above 90% (probably 99.x%). The training algorithm, training- and attack-params should be visible in the code.
The problem, as already stated in the title is, that the accuracy is stuck at 5% after training ~3000 of 39002 training inputs in the first epoch. (GermanTrafficSignRecognitionBenchmark, [GTSRB](http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=news)).

When training without and adversariy loss function, the accuracy does not get stuck after 3000 samples, but continues to rise > 0.95 in the first epoch.

When substituting the network with a lenet-5, alexnet and vgg19, the code works as expected, and an accuracy absolutely comparabele to the non-adversarial, categorical_corssentropy lossfunction is achieved. I've also tried running the procedure using solely tf-cpu and different versions of tensorflow, the result is always the same.

Code for obtaining ResNet-50:

```
def build_resnet50(num_classes, img_size):
    from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
    from tensorflow.keras import Model
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
    resnet = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=img_size)
    x = Flatten(input_shape=resnet.output.shape)(resnet.output)
    x = Dense(1024, activation='sigmoid')(x)
    predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='pred')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=[resnet.input], outputs=[predictions])
    return model
```

Training:

```
def lr_schedule(epoch):
    # decreasing learning rate depending on epoch
    return 0.001 * (0.1 ** int(epoch / 10))


def train_model(model, xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest, lr=0.001, batch_size=32, 
epochs=10, result_folder=""):
    from cleverhans.attacks import FastGradientMethod
    from cleverhans.utils_keras import KerasModelWrapper
    import tensorflow as tf

    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler, ModelCheckpoint
    sgd = SGD(lr=lr, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

    model(model.input)

    wrap = KerasModelWrapper(model)
    sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
    fgsm = FastGradientMethod(wrap, sess=sess)
    fgsm_params = {'eps': 0.01,
                   'clip_min': 0.,
                   'clip_max': 1.}

    loss = get_adversarial_loss(model, fgsm, fgsm_params)

    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=(xtest, ytest),
                    epochs=epochs,
                    callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)])
```

Loss-function:

```
def get_adversarial_loss(model, fgsm, fgsm_params):
    def adv_loss(y, preds):
         import tensorflow as tf

        tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(False) #turn off dropout during input gradient calculation, to avoid unconnected gradients

        # Cross-entropy on the legitimate examples
        cross_ent = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y, preds)

        # Generate adversarial examples
        x_adv = fgsm.generate(model.input, **fgsm_params)
        # Consider the attack to be constant
        x_adv = tf.stop_gradient(x_adv)

        # Cross-entropy on the adversarial examples
        preds_adv = model(x_adv)
        cross_ent_adv = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y, preds_adv)

        tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True) #turn back on

        return 0.5 * cross_ent + 0.5 * cross_ent_adv
    return adv_loss
```

Versions used:
tf+tf-gpu: 1.14.0
keras: 2.3.1
cleverhans: > 3.0.1 - latest version pulled from github

Answer (score 0):

It is a side-effect of the way we estimate the moving averages on BatchNormalization.

The mean and variance of the training data that you used are different from the ones of the dataset used to train the ResNet50. Because the momentum on the BatchNormalization has a default value of 0.99, with only 10 iterations it does not converge quickly enough to the correct values for the moving mean and variance. This is not obvious during training when the learning_phase is 1 because BN uses the mean/variance of the batch. Nevertheless when we set learning_phase to 0, the incorrect mean/variance values which are learned during training significantly affect the accuracy.

You can fix this problem by below approachs:

1. More iterations

Reduce the size of the batch from 32 to 16(to perform more updates per epoch) and increase the number of epochs from 10 to 250. This way the moving average and variance will converge to the correct values.

2. Change the momentum of BatchNormalization

Keep the number of iterations fixed but change the momentum of the BatchNormalization layer to update more aggressively the rolling mean and variance (not recommended for production models).

On the original snippet, add the following code between reading the base_model and defining the new layers:

```
# ....
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

# PATCH MOMENTUM - START
import json
conf = json.loads(base_model.to_json())
for l in conf['config']['layers']:
    if l['class_name'] == 'BatchNormalization':
        l['config']['momentum'] = 0.5


m = Model.from_config(conf['config'])
for l in base_model.layers:
    m.get_layer(l.name).set_weights(l.get_weights())

base_model = m
# PATCH MOMENTUM - END

x = base_model.output
# ....
```

Would also recommend you to try another hack provided bu us [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230762/with-resnet50-the-validation-accuracy-and-loss-is-not-changing/61656540#61656540).

Comment: @PlassMa - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, neither of the options work...
I think it's not an issue related to not converging fast enough, as non-adversarial training yields an accuracy of > .95 after 1 epoch...

Comment: @PlassMa - Interesting. So you are saying the non-adversarial Resnet training gives >95% accuracy whereas adversarial Resnet training stuck at 5% accuracy? The same adversarial training with lenet-5, alexnet and vgg19 are working as expected? Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230762/with-resnet50-the-validation-accuracy-and-loss-is-not-changing/61656540#61656540 approach too? Also is it possible to share the completed code in google colab file and share the link here?